# Server Side PDF Generation

Tags: php, pdf

We've got a restaurant client who has menus on their web site. The web site content is all dynamically generated from a CMS. All the menus also have links to download a PDF. Right now, it's a manual process of creating/updating the document in InDesign, exporting as a PDF and overwriting the old file on the server.

Ideally it'd be able to automatically generate a PDF that looks similar to if someone on a Mac printed and saved as a PDF.

We're looking for a way for the process to be more animated. We've looked at both f-pdf & HTML2PDF, but neither one do exactly what we want. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: What exactly do you want, and what platform are you running it on, and do you have a budget or do you need it to be free?

Comment: what's wrong with `fpdf`? actually `ufpdf` and `tcpdf` are quite similar to `fpdf`

Comment: Did you tried Zend? http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html

Comment: @Orbling Looking for the output of a HTML (PHP really) page to PDF automatially.
@k102 fdpf didn't have the CSS formatting we wanted.
@Mihai Will check that one out. Thanks
@Chris Will check that out as well.

Comment: @Keefer: I don't find any of the PDF libraries do HTML->PDF particularly well.  But TCPDF is the easiest in that regard, providing you stick clearly to what is supported.  Any reason it needs to be from HTML to PDF, usually people build PDFs directly or you can use some other markup with an existing route to PDF (such that can be automated via PHP), LaTeX for instance, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're working in PHP, have you tried [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)?

Comment: Got to second this: TCPDF is quite nice. I've used it in the past to generate invoices in real time from an accounting system, and it just works.

Answer (score 1):

Use LibreOffice:

```
soffice.exe --headless --convert-to pdf file.xls
```

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Comment: hm... i think it's better to use `ufpdf` instead decoding all the time =)

Comment: I believe in the next project I'll definitely try!

Answer (score 0):

We are using [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/). Its not the easiest to use but the result is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

- for "generic convertions with LibreOffice/OpenOffice", see also [Universal Network Objects (UNO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Network_Objects): there are Python, Java, etc. bridges for use it.  There are applications for simplify the use for convertions, see [Docvert](http://holloway.co.nz/docvert/) and  *JODConverter* ([jODconverter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jodconverter) and [pyODconverter](https://github.com/mirkonasato/pyodconverter)).
- for "HTML to PDF" using CSS2 and CSS3, see also [PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/), a professional conversor.

All of then can be called as web-service or exec by PHP.